# How to build a Docker image from a base image on public registry and add a backend service?

Tags: docker

My requirement is to build a Dockerfile which uses an image hosted on the public Docker hub. I need to add a backend service to it (e.g. a web server), and preserve the entry point in the original image. I do not have the original Dockerfile for the public Docker image. How would I achieve that?

As a starting point, I have below Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/xhofe/alist:v3.16.0

ENV LOG_PATH   /var/logs
ENV LOG_LEVEL  DEBUG
ENV MY_WEB_SERVER_PATH /mywebserver
## TODO: Add code to install a backend service without altering the entry point
## Use python -m http.server 8000 as an example
```

How to modify this Dockerfile to install and run a backend service (use `python -m http.server 8000` as an example), while preserving the entry point of the original image?

Comment: `I do not have the original Dockerfile for the public Docker image.` Looks like it's [this one](https://github.com/alist-org/alist/blob/main/Dockerfile).

Comment: Given that the [entrypoint script](https://github.com/alist-org/alist/blob/main/entrypoint.sh) doesn't give you a way to start another service, I don't see any way you could accomplish this without modifying the entry point.

Comment: Does this need to run in the same container, or in the same image?  A container only runs a single process and it's usually easier to run multiple containers than to try to work around this.  You might be able to run the original image unmodified, and then run a second container (its image either built `FROM python` or as you've shown) that runs the backend.